# Running sql file on postgres db with Go not getting all results

Tags: postgresql, go

I have tried with both pgx and pq libs and I cannot figure out how to get the results from 2 select statements

I get an sql file that needs to be run on multiple databases. The sql comes from the dev team, as my team is not DBAs or Devs my requirement is to run the sql as it is given to us. When I scan the results from
this test sql I get the results from the first select statement but not from the second. Am I approaching this wrong? I want to avoid having to parse the file for each statement/code block and run each line individually. I ran into a separate issue with pgx so I am using pq for now until I can get the other issue  sorted but if anyone knows how to do this with pgx I can work around the second issue

test.sql

```
select * from mytable;
DO $$
DECLARE s record;
BEGIN
    FOR s IN SELECT name FROM mytable
           LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'Tenant Name: %', s;
       END LOOP;
   END;
$$
;;
select name from mytable;
```

RunQuery func

```
func RunQuery(query string) (Results, error) {
    var myresults Results
    connectionString := "postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/dbname?sslmode=disable"
    base, err := pq.NewConnector(connectionString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Notice listner stores any notices in a slice to be returned after query is run
    connector := pq.ConnectorWithNoticeHandler(
        base,
        func(notice *pq.Error) {
            myresults.notices = append(myresults.notices, notice.Message)
        })

    db := sql.OpenDB(connector)
    defer db.Close()

    response, err := db.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //var allRows [][]string
    var row []string
    row, err = response.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error getting column names")
        return myresults, err
    }
    myresults.allRows = append(myresults.allRows, row)

    raw := make([][]byte, len(row))       // byte slice is one column in the returned row. The slice of byte slice is to store multiple columns in one slice
    dest := make([]interface{}, len(row)) // slice of interface to insert unknown number of returned columns

    // We cannot scan directly into a slice of bytes and need to use an empty inteface to scan into
    // This assigns the address of the i th index to dest so when we scan into dest, raw slice is populated with the data we need to work on
    for i := range dest {
        dest[i] = &raw[i] // Use pointers to byte slices for Scan
    }

    for response.Next() {
        // scan row into the slice of interface which holds the addresses of raw variable
        err := response.Scan(dest...)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("unable to scan row")
            break
        }

        row := make([]string, len(myresults.allRows[0]))
        for i, v := range raw { // loop through slice of byte slice
            if v == nil {
                row[i] = "" // nil object returned from db. cannot have nil string
            } else {
                row[i] = string(v)
            }
        }
        myresults.allRows = append(myresults.allRows, row)
    }
    return myresults, nil
```

I get the results from the first select statement and the RAISE NOTICEs but not the second select statement. I get the same results if I put only 2 select statements in the sql file

test2.sql

```
select * from mytable;
select name from mytable;
```

Comment: Have you tried [NextResultSet()](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows.NextResultSet)? (see [this example](https://go.dev/doc/database/querying#multiple_result_sets)).

Answer (score 0):

except

> I want to avoid having to parse the file for each statement/code block and run each line individually

which is another story(it's better to have statement separator and run each statement separately IMO), and except:

> anyone knows how to do this with pgx I can work around the second issue

which again is another issue, your base issue was handling notifications, you have a pl/pgsql block which sends multiple notifications and your connection get stock on receiving them, let's change your code step by step:

1. Write new method to establish connection and return ***sql.DB** variable as **Connection pool manager**

```golang
func Connect() *sql.DB {
    connectionString := "postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/dbname?sslmode=disable"
    base, err := pq.NewConnector(connectionString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Notice listner stores any notices in a slice to be returned after query is run
    connector := pq.ConnectorWithNoticeHandler(
        base,
        func(notice *pq.Error) {
            myresults.notices = append(myresults.notices, notice.Message)
        })

    return sql.OpenDB(connector)
}
```

2. In **RunQuery** method take one more variable with type: ***sql.DB**

```golang
func RunQuery(db *sql.DB, query string) (Results, error) {
    var myresults Results

    response, err := db.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //var allRows [][]string
    var row []string
    row, err = response.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error getting column names")
        return myresults, err
    }
    myresults.allRows = append(myresults.allRows, row)

    raw := make([][]byte, len(row))       // byte slice is one column in the returned row. The slice of byte slice is to store multiple columns in one slice
    dest := make([]interface{}, len(row)) // slice of interface to insert unknown number of returned columns

    // We cannot scan directly into a slice of bytes and need to use an empty inteface to scan into
    // This assigns the address of the i th index to dest so when we scan into dest, raw slice is populated with the data we need to work on
    for i := range dest {
        dest[i] = &raw[i] // Use pointers to byte slices for Scan
    }

    for response.Next() {
        // scan row into the slice of interface which holds the addresses of raw variable
        err := response.Scan(dest...)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("unable to scan row")
            break
        }

        row := make([]string, len(myresults.allRows[0]))
        for i, v := range raw { // loop through slice of byte slice
            if v == nil {
                row[i] = "" // nil object returned from db. cannot have nil string
            } else {
                row[i] = string(v)
            }
        }
        myresults.allRows = append(myresults.allRows, row)
    }
    return myresults, nil
}
```

3. Add new method to Send notifies by calling pl/pgsql block(we have to call this method later in a background go-routine to don't block our main go-routine):

```golang
func SendNotifs(db *sql.DB, notifs string) {
    result, err := db.Exec(notifs)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("execute notify result:", result)
}
```

4. Add a channel to receive notifies and store them into results and send channel to **notify handler** method:

```golang
var channel chan string

func NotifyHandler(notice *pq.Error) {
    channel <- notice.Message
}
```

5. In your main method, first call **connector** method, then **RunQuery** for each query statement, then call send notify, after that you should wait for it's response, the full code is like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func Connect(connectionString string, channel chan string) *sql.DB {
    base, err := pq.NewConnector(connectionString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Notice listner stores any notices in a slice to be returned after query is run
    connector := pq.ConnectorWithNoticeHandler(
        base,
        NotifyHandler,
    )

    return sql.OpenDB(connector)
}

type Results struct {
    allRows [][]string
    notices []string
}

var channel chan string

func NotifyHandler(notice *pq.Error) {
    channel <- notice.Message
}

func RunQuery(db *sql.DB, query string, myresults *Results) error {
    response, err := db.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //var allRows [][]string
    var row []string
    row, err = response.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error getting column names")
        return err
    }
    myresults.allRows = append(myresults.allRows, row)

    raw := make([][]byte, len(row))       // byte slice is one column in the returned row. The slice of byte slice is to store multiple columns in one slice
    dest := make([]interface{}, len(row)) // slice of interface to insert unknown number of returned columns

    // We cannot scan directly into a slice of bytes and need to use an empty inteface to scan into
    // This assigns the address of the i th index to dest so when we scan into dest, raw slice is populated with the data we need to work on
    for i := range dest {
        dest[i] = &raw[i] // Use pointers to byte slices for Scan
    }

    for response.Next() {
        // scan row into the slice of interface which holds the addresses of raw variable
        err := response.Scan(dest...)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("unable to scan row")
            break
        }

        row := make([]string, len(myresults.allRows[0]))
        for i, v := range raw { // loop through slice of byte slice
            if v == nil {
                row[i] = "" // nil object returned from db. cannot have nil string
            } else {
                row[i] = string(v)
            }
        }
        emptyColumns := 0
        for _, field := range row {
            if len(field) == 0 {
                emptyColumns++
            }
        }
        if emptyColumns == len(myresults.allRows[0]) {
            break
        }
        myresults.allRows = append(myresults.allRows, row)
    }
    return nil
}

func SendNotifs(db *sql.DB, notifs string) {
    result, err := db.Exec(notifs)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("execute notify result:", result)
}

func main() {
    sqlFileContents, err := os.ReadFile("test.sql")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    channel = make(chan string)

    connectionString := "postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/dbname?sslmode=disable"
    db := Connect(connectionString, channel)
    statements := strings.Split(string(sqlFileContents), ";")
    var myresults Results
    err = RunQuery(db, statements[0], &myresults)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("query 1:", myresults)

    // should run in background
    go SendNotifs(db, strings.Join(statements[1:6], ";")+";")

// to break after receiving all of notifies
NotifyWaitLoop:
    for {
        select {
        case notify := <-channel:
            myresults.notices = append(myresults.notices, notify)
        case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
            if len(myresults.notices) == len(myresults.allRows)-1 /*-1 is for columns which you have stored in query*/ {
                log.Println("all notifs are received")
                break NotifyWaitLoop
            }
        }
    }

    log.Println("notify result:", myresults)
    err = RunQuery(db, statements[7], &myresults)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("query 2:", myresults)
}
```

output:

```
query 1: {[[id name] [1 a] [2 b] [3 c] [4 d]] []}
execute notify result: {0xc0001ee000 0}
all notifs are received
notify result: {[[id name] [1 a] [2 b] [3 c] [4 d]] [Tenant Name: (a) Tenant Name: (b) Tenant Name: (c) Tenant Name: (d)]}
query 2: {[[id name] [1 a] [2 b] [3 c] [4 d] [name] [a ] [b ] [c ] [d ]] [Tenant Name: (a) Tenant Name: (b) Tenant Name: (c) Tenant Name: (d)]}
```